# Message Queue: segmentation fault when executing task

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads, message-queue

Can't seem to make any progress on this C assignment, hopefully somebody immediately spots the problem: Goal is to implement a thread pool using a POSIX message queue. The threads are created at start and then receive task after task from the message queue. The threads are expected to receive a 16 byte struct of type *task_t* that contains the function as well as a pointer to the arguments it should be executed with.

I get a segmentation fault as soon as the first task is being worked on by a thread, i.e. when executing function *foo* which can be accessed in threadPoolFun as *task_ptr->func* and is supposed to be run with argument *task_ptr->this*:

```
void * threadPoolFun(void * arg) {
    task_t * task_ptr;
    int size = attr.mq_msgsize; //size = 16
    char buf[size];
    while (1) {
        int ret_val = mq_receive(task_queue, buf, size, NULL);
        if (ret_val == -1) {
            perror("Error receiving message: ");
        }
        task_ptr = (task_t *) buf;
        if (task_ptr->func == NULL) {
            break;
        }
        task_ptr->func(task_ptr->this);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Segmentation fault:

> ```
> Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> #0  0x000000000040086a in foo (arg=0x7ffdd71fdfd0) at all_in_one.c:37
> 37        td->retVal = (double) td->tid;
> [Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7fec2d544700 (LWP 9853))]
> (gdb) list
> 32    fooTask_t; // type for this tasks
> 33    
> 34    //definition of task: write tid to retVal
> 35    void foo(void * arg) {
> 36        fooTask_t *td = (fooTask_t *) arg;
> 37        td->retVal = (double) td->tid;
> 38    }
> 39    
> 40    // initialize task 
> 41    void fooInit(fooTask_t * t) {
> (gdb) backtrace
> #0  0x000000000040086a in foo (arg=0x7ffdd71fdfd0) at all_in_one.c:37
> #1  0x0000000000400b8c in threadPoolFun (arg=0x0) at all_in_one.c:118
> #2  0x00007fec2f1196ba in start_thread (arg=0x7fec2d544700)
>     at pthread_create.c:333
> #3  0x00007fec2ee4f41d in clone ()
> ```

Full code:

```
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//number of threads
#define NTH 4
//number of tasks
#define NTASKS 10

void * threadPoolFun(void * arg);
typedef void( * taskfun_t)(void * );

//minimal task data structure: func to be executed with args this, abstraction from actual task
typedef struct minTaskDataStruct {
    void * this;
    taskfun_t func;
}
task_t;

//data structure for actual task
typedef struct fooDataStruct {
    // mandatory entries
    void * this; // pointer to this structure
    taskfun_t func; // function with signature: void foo(void *)

    // data for individual task instances
    long tid; // task id                 
    double retVal; // return value

}
fooTask_t; // type for this tasks

//definition of task: write tid to retVal
void foo(void * arg) {
    fooTask_t *td = (fooTask_t *) arg;
    td->retVal = (double) td->tid;
}

// initialize task 
void fooInit(fooTask_t * t) {
    t-> this = t; // set this pointer
    t-> func = foo; // set task function
}

//data structure for threads
pthread_t th[NTH];
//data structure for task queue attributes
static struct mq_attr attr;
//task queue
mqd_t task_queue;
//create task structs and store them in array td
fooTask_t td[NTASKS];

int main() {


    printf("Setting up tasks\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < NTASKS; i++) {
        fooTask_t task;
        task.tid = i;
        fooInit(&task);
        td[i] = task;
    }

    // set attributes
    attr.mq_flags = 0; /* Flags: 0 or O_NONBLOCK */
    attr.mq_maxmsg = 10; /* Max. # of messages on queue */
    attr.mq_msgsize = 16; /* Max. message size (bytes) */
    printf("Opening task queue\n");
    // set up task queue
    task_queue = mq_open("/my_task_queue_mq", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0700, & attr);

    //create threads with default attributes, pass threadpool function
    //threads will run as long as func passed to them is not NULL

    for (long i = 0; i < NTH; i++) {
    printf("Creating thread %ld\n", i);
        pthread_create( & th[i], NULL, threadPoolFun, NULL);
    }
    //send tasks to queue, tasks to be consumed by threads, only send first 16 bytes
    for (int i = 0; i < NTASKS; i++) {
    printf("Sending task %d\n", i); 
        mq_send(task_queue, (const char * ) &td[i], sizeof(task_t), 0);
    }

    //send dummy tasks with func==NULL to terminate threads
    for (int i = 0; i < NTASKS; i++) {
    printf("Sending dummy task %d\n", i); 
        task_t dummy_task;
        dummy_task.this = & dummy_task;
        dummy_task.func = NULL;
        mq_send(task_queue, (const char * ) & dummy_task, sizeof(task_t), 0);
    }

    //verify task execution
    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NTASKS; i++) {
        sum1 += td[i].retVal;
        sum2 += i;
    }

    if (sum1 == sum2) {
        printf("Success: Sum1 %d equals Sum2 %d", sum1, sum2);
    } else {
        printf("Fail: Sum1 %d does not Sum2 %d", sum1, sum2);
    }
    return 0;
}

//threadPoolFun function definition
void * threadPoolFun(void * arg) {
    task_t * task_ptr;
    int size = attr.mq_msgsize; //size = 16
    char buf[size];
    while (1) {
        int ret_val = mq_receive(task_queue, buf, size, NULL);
        if (ret_val == -1) {
            perror("Error receiving message: ");
        }
        task_ptr = (task_t *) buf;
        if (task_ptr->func == NULL) {
            break;
        }
        task_ptr->func(task_ptr->this);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, many thanks already in advance!
Lawrence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use addresses to objects on the stack after they are no longer there. You have this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NTASKS; i++) {
    fooTask_t task;
    task.tid = i;
    fooInit(&task);
    td[i] = task;
}
```

`&task` is such a pointer. This is easy to fix, since you already have a place where you store the task. Here is better code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NTASKS; i++) {
    fooTask_t task;
    task.tid = i;
    td[i] = task;
    fooInit(&td[i]);
}
```

The second place where this happens is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NTASKS; i++) {
printf("Sending dummy task %d\n", i); 
    task_t dummy_task;
    dummy_task.this = & dummy_task;
    dummy_task.func = NULL;
    mq_send(task_queue, (const char * ) & dummy_task, sizeof(task_t), 0);
}
```

Since the dummy tasks don't need to be individually saved anywhere, you can move out the declaration of dummy_task, so it will live during the whole execution of `main`:

```
task_t dummy_task;
dummy_task.this = & dummy_task;
dummy_task.func = NULL;

//send dummy tasks with func==NULL to terminate threads
for (int i = 0; i < NTASKS; i++) {
fprintf(stderr, "Sending dummy task %d\n", i); 
    mq_send(task_queue, (const char * ) & dummy_task, sizeof(task_t), 0);
}
```

After this, there are still synchronization problems with your algorithm, but that is a separate problem, which I leave to you.

I changed the printing from stdout to stderr, since the former is buffered, and got lost when the program crashed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, you saved my day! I can see the problem now and am now moving on to fix the synch problem. Cheers!